# How to set n_batches_per_layer in tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow

How should I think when setting the n_batches_per_layer?
I currently select 10 from [1, 10, 100] as a result of hyperparameter tuning.

But when I thought about it. If I divide my data by the batch_size, I get 6.8 batches.
So I'm thinking that perhaps 7 would be better, that would cover all the data, with minimal overlap.

I guess my question boils down to, what does this parameter actually do?

Answer (score 0):

This parameter defines the number of batches to collect statistics per layer. From the github code, when `examples_per_layer` is lower, training is faster. Now, `n_batches_per_layer` is defined as data size/ batch size, which means we need to put a higher value for faster training.

References:
[Github Code](https://github.com/nicolov/gradient_boosting_tensorflow_xgboost)
[Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesRegressor)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.